# Nginx location match by suffix

Tags: nginx

Need to match all the URLs ending with `commerce/authenticate` and can't get to a generic enough rule.

Here are the URLs I need to match:

1. local.site.com/api/commerce/authenticate
2. local.site.com/en-us/api/commerce/authenticate
3. local.site.com/madrid/api/commerce/authenticate
4. local.site.com/madrid/en-us/api/commerce/authenticate

My try:

```
      # <My attempt>
      location ~ .*api/commerce/authenticate {
        limit_except POST {
          deny all;
        }
      }

     # This also exists <madrid-path>
     location ^~ /madrid {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /madrid/index.php?$query_string;
       location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
         ...
       }         
     }
```

The above code isn't working(matching all given URLs) but, if I move `<My attempt>` within `<madrid-path>` it works for:

3. local.site.com/madrid/api/commerce/authenticate
4. local.site.com/madrid/en-us/api/commerce/authenticate`

But as I explained above, I need a general rule which works with root cases as well.

Comment: If I remember correctly, try_files causes trouble for fastcgi_splt_path_info.  Look it up.   Your "<My attempt>" should match cases 1 and 2, but also "local.site.com/api/commerce/authenticate/whatever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` character in `location ^~ /madrid` prevents nginx for checking regular expressions after checking this location.

Try this configuration:

```
location ~ api/commerce/authenticate$ {
    limit_except POST {
        deny all;
    }
}

location /madrid {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /madrid/index.php?$query_string;
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        ...
    }
}
```

With this configuration and request being `/madrid/api/commerce/authenticate`, nginx first sees that prefix matches `/madrid`. It remembers the match and then proceeds to check regular expression blocks. Then the regular expression block matches, and nginx will use it.

If the regular expression block does not match, nginx uses the `/madrid` location.

Further details on nginx location processing rules are documented in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks for explaining.